# Problema com hashlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

Estou com um problema para usar a 'hashlib' do python, pois estou comparando as hashs geradas com a linha abaixo, com as hashs geradas no site : 'http://temp.crypo.com/sha512.htm', mas ao comparar os resultados vejo que são diferentes.

Código usado para gerar as hashs:

```
def encoding(hash_test):
    return hashlib.sha512(bytes(hash_test, encoding='UTF-16LE')).hexdigest()
```

Obs: me baseei no código da documentação do python(https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) para montar este.

Hash gerada pelo código:

> 3a94b49c382f9c39a83e0ae31a26bdcf23f74b6c81eb8779f1305b840aaabc94e3921d6f9d0e25b15f6569c42dc24f9524540b765147699e33d903dc6a85a354

Hash gerada pelo site:

> b123e9e19d217169b981a61188920f9d28638709a5132201684d792b9264271b7f09157ed4321b1c097f7a4abecfc0977d40a7ee599c845883bd1074ca23c4af

Obs: Usei em ambos site e código a palavra 'teste'(sem áspas) para gerar as hashes.

O que tem de errado com o código para que os resultados sejam diferentes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Código:

```
import hashlib


def hash_sha512( text ):
    return hashlib.sha512( text.encode('utf-8') ).hexdigest()

print hash_sha512( "teste" )
```

Saída:

> b123e9e19d217169b981a61188920f9d28638709a5132201684d792b9264271b7f09157ed4321b1c097f7a4abecfc0977d40a7ee599c845883bd1074ca23c4af

Comment: Ao usar esse código o python retorna um 'TypeError', e diz que objetos-unicode devem ser codificados antes de passarem pelo algoritmo de hash. Obs:em python não há necessidade de ';', no final das linhas.

Comment: @Gabriel: Resposta editada.